# startForeground() always shows a popup on Samsung 8.0 device

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I encountered a problem with Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge showing a popup notification every time I use `startForeground()` in my foreground service for status update in its notification.

Firstly, this issue was present on all Android 8.0 devices but was easily fixed with my notification channel priority set to `IMPORTANCE_LOW`. But the problem remains for the Samsung device.

So, the question is, how do I update my foreground service notification silently on Samsung 8.0+ devices?

My code is as follows.

Application class:

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //other code
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannels(listOf(
                    //
                    NotificationChannel(MY_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, "My channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW).apply {
                        setSound(null, null)
                    }
                    //
            ))
        }
    }
```

Service starting foreground:

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MY_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                .setColor(App.context().resources.getColor(R.color.primary_dark))
                .setContentText(if (/*logic*/) "This" else "That")
                .addAction(0, if (enable) "Disable" else "Enable", firstIntent)
                .addAction(0, "Another action", secondIntent)
                .build()

        startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
```

Comment: Why do you use startForeground multiple times? It makes sense for android to show your notification multiple times. You can should show (start) when it is not already started. and startForeground will always show a notification.

Comment: @AdibFaramarzi I've changed the code to check whether there is an ongoing notification already and use `NotificationManager` to update the notification instead of another `startForeground()`. No difference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotificationCompat.Builder` has `setOnlyAlertOnce` method and when set to `true` it would show the popup only once.

Answer (score 4):

I've been investigating the same. Best you could do is create the notification without a channel. Service starts with nothing in the tray. Seems to work for me.

`NotificationCompat.Builder(this)`

However, this constructor is deprecated in 26.1.0

Comment: I don't think you can run a foreground service without any notification.

Comment: Correct, a Notification is required. However, in Android 8, if you create that Notification without a Channel it will not appear in the tray. In my experience the foreground service still ran but the Notification wasn’t visible. 

But note going forward this way of creating Notifications without a Channel is deprecated.